Problems with text alignment in paragraphs when creating a LaTeX template in RMarkdown
Although I have a lot of experience with R, I'm fairly new to LaTeX, and it's proving to be quite a challenge. I work as a biologist and my current project is to automate the creation of labels for various plant species. I'm using the LabelleR package for this task (although that's not where I'm finding the problems).
The process consists of inserting a template written in LaTeX into the package to customise the labels. In addition, a dataset is required in which each row represents a plant, and the columns contain different sections of the label. The problem arises when trying to include more than one line of text in a cell; the second line is misaligned with the first, as if the spacing does not affect the position of the second line. It seems that only the first line of text is affected by the \hspace command, while the subsequent lines are not affected at all.
I have problems with params location and area.description.
Here is my code:

for (i in seq_along(params$collection.i)){
  cat("
\\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=black]\n
\\pagenumbering{gobble}
\\begin{center}
{\\fontsize{25pt}{80pt}\\selectfont\\bf ",params$subtitle,"} \\\\
\\end{center}
\\begin{center}
\\bigskip
{\\fontsize{40pt}{100pt}\\selectfont\\bf", params$title, "} \\\\
\\end{center}
\\vspace{0.5cm}
\\begin{center}
{\\fontsize{30pt}{100pt}\\selectfont\\bf {\\emph{",params$taxon.i[i],"}} ",params$author.i[i],"} \\\\
\\end{center}
\\begin{flushright}
\\hspace{0.5cm}
{\\fontsize{20pt}{100pt}\\selectfont Det.", params$det.i[i]," ", params$date.det.i[i],"~~~~}\\\\
\\end{flushright}
\\begin{flushleft}
\\hspace{0.5cm}
{\\fontsize{30pt}{100pt}\\selectfont", params$location.i[i],"} \\\\
\\vspace{0.25cm}
\\hspace{0.5cm}
{\\fontsize{30pt}{100pt}\\selectfont Altitud:", params$elevation.i[i],"}\\\\
\\vspace{0.25cm}
\\hspace{0.5cm}
{\\fontsize{30pt}{100pt}\\selectfont Lat y Lon:", params$latitude.i[i], " | ", params$longitude.i[i],"} \\\\
\\vspace{0.5cm}
\\hspace{0.5cm}
{\\fontsize{25pt}{100pt}\\selectfont", params$area.description.i[i],"} \\\\
\\vspace{2cm}
\\end{flushleft}
\\vfill
\\begin{flushleft}
\\hspace{0.5cm}
{\\fontsize{30pt}{100pt}\\selectfont\\bf Colector: ",params$collector.i[i]," ",params$collection.i[i],"} \\\\
\\hspace{0.5cm}
{\\fontsize{25pt}{100pt}\\selectfont\\bf Fecha: ",params$date.i[i],"} \\\\
\\end{flushleft}
\\vspace{1.5cm}
\\end{mdframed}\n
\\pagebreak")
}

The label I'm waiting for:

The label that I get instead:

If anyone has a solution I would be very grateful. Thank you very much in advance!
Nico

Welcome to TeX.SE! please show us the resulting Tex code!

Hello! The resulting labels for the tex-codes were attached in my first comment. I don't know if that's you mean

You added  \hspace{0.5cm} before each field to increase the left margin, but this is like making this MWE and expecting the word "baz" aligned with "foo":
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\hspace{6cm} foo bar baz
\end{document}

That is, \hspace add a horizontal space in the row where it is. End dot.

Remove template="myherbarium-or-whatever.Rmd",

Add keep.files=TRUE to recover the default template herbarium.Rmd

Edit the new template to add after \\begin{mdframed}[  options like:


innerleftmargin=5em,
innerrightmargin=5em,


Replace the deprecated \bf by the safer \bfseries

Other changes that you want, such as centering the taxon, changing font sizes, etc., but without using \hspace{0.5cm} (nor \vspace{0.5cm}, leave the \vfills in their place, you do not want fixed vertical spaces if text heights could change too much).




Note: your code (just the R chunk of the template) is not reproducible "as is" and it needs too much reverse engineering to test it properly. A better MWE would have been complete R script to generate the example like:
library(labeleR)
herbarium.table <- data.frame(...)
create_herbarium_label (data = herbarium.table, ... ,template="Mytemplate.Rmd")

And, of course, also adding the complete Mytemplate.Rmd, including the YAML header, so that any R+LaTeX user could have run it.
Alternatively, for LaTeX users without R, it would have been a perfect MWE to use keep.files=TRUE to obtain the .tex version, and then reducing the irrelevant parts for the issue (title, font sizes, bolds fonts, mdframed box, etc.) while still compilable "as is" and still showing the issue. This means reducing the MWE to just a few lines, which is laborious but teaches more than 10 lessons.
